# Extending a set of existing tables into a dynamic client defined structure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have an old repair database that has alot of relational tables and it works as it should but i need to update it to be able to handle different clients ( areas ) - currenty this is done as a single client only.

So i need to extend the tables and the sql statements so ex i can login as user A and he will see his own system only and user B will have his own system too.

Is it correctly understood that you wouldnt create new tables for each client but just add a clientID to every record in every ( base )  table and then just filter with a clientid in all sql statements to be able to achieve multiple clients ?

Is this also something that would work ( how is it done ) on hosted solutions ? Am worried about performance if thats an issue lets say i had 500 clients ( i wont but from a theoretic viewpoint ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal situation is to add a client key to each table where appropriate.  Many tables don't need them -- such as reference tables.

This is preferred for many reasons:

- You have the data for all clients in one place, so you can readily answers a question such as "what is the average X for each client".
- If you change the data structure, then it affects all clients at the same time.
- Your backup and restore strategy is only implemented once.
- Your optimization is only implemented once.

This is not always the best solution.  You might have requirements that specify that data must be separated -- in which case, each client should be in a separate database.  However, indexes on the additional keys are probably a minor consideration and you shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before. The problem with adding the key to every table is that you say you have a working system, and this means every query needs to be updated.

Probably the easiest is to create a new database for each client, so that the only thing you need to change is the connection string. This also means you can get automated query tools for example to work without worrying about cross-client data leakage.

And it also allows you to backup, transfer, delete a single client easily as well.

There are of course pros and cons to this approach, but it will simplify the development effort. Also remember that if you plan to spin it up in a cloud environment then spinning up databases like this is also very easy.

Comment: If yoy are to do a cloud solution from scratch would new database for each be the way its done ? I could see abit of an issue having multiple client data in one database so running it in its own would be a nice and easy way i assume ?

Comment: It will all come down to the pricing, but the ease of adding a new cloud database makes it very attractive. You might be able to offload the price to your customers, which also means you can scale up and down performance for each one as needeed. You can even "white label" your app so that customers can banner it how they like.